# Laravel json where not working

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel

I try `where` query in json structure. But always returns `null`. Am I doing wrong ?

My scope method in Model :

```
public function scopeWhereDeveloper(Builder $scope)
{
  return $scope->where('parameters->developer','yes');
}
```

My static method in Model :

```
public static function getDeveloper($columns = ['*'])
{
    return static::whereDeveloper()->first($columns);
}
```

Migration :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('user_name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->json('parameters')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }
```

Test method :

```
/** @test */
public function it_can_get_admin_developer_by_parameter()
{
    $admin = create(Admin::class, ['parameters' => ['developer' => 'yes']]);

    $developer = Admin::getDeveloper();

    dd($developer); // return null

    $this->assertEquals($admin->email,$developer->email);

}
```

So what I do ?

---

> So interesting.When I using this query : `return->where('parametersdeveloper','yes');` always returns null in. But when I test in `HomeController` with ::getDeveloper()` then I can get the user. Why did this happen ?

Comment: what is your Laravel version?

Comment: Laravel version is `5.6`

Comment: What's the result of `dd($admin->getAttributes())` in your test?

Comment: `array:8 [
  "full_name" => "Jalen"
  "user_name" => "mertz.kevon"
  "email" => "rwill@kozey.net"
  "password" => "$2y$04$LJ9XSw1cu1i8e.WurqNCZe09t4zxFiUTaggZluuKK2hbC.52kcbba"
  "parameters" => "{"developer":"yes"}"
  "updated_at" => "2018-04-16 15:30:51"
  "created_at" => "2018-04-16 15:30:51"
  "id" => 1
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name a scope with a `where` prefix. Eloquent will assume that you're trying to use shorthand for `->where('developer')`.

Rename your scope to something like `scopeDeveloper`

Comment: @ysfkaya If you rename it to `scopeDeveloper` you need to use it as `Model::developer()`

Comment: Yes I noticed, it works in `Controller` but still returns `null` in Testing. Do you know why?